# How to find the detailed Dimensions information of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

In 5 digital images I have determined the 2d coordinates of detected objects.

The resulting array (list) can be downloaded from here: http://pastebin.com/7bE0CEJ5

```
array= {{{1, {533.286, 574.643}}, ... , {443, {371., 3.5}}}}
```

`array` consists of 5 subarrays (for each image one):

`Dimensions[array[[1]]` = `{443, 2}`

`Dimensions[array[[2]]` = `{443, 2}`

`Dimensions[array[[3]]` = `{444, 2}`

`Dimensions[array[[4]]` = `{442, 2}`

`Dimensions[array[[5]]` = `{443, 2}`

If I try to show the `Dimensions` of array, I get the number of images:

`Dimensions[array]` = `{5}`

How can I get the complete `Dimensions` information of the list `array`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your subarrays are not all of equal dimensions. In particular subarrays 3 and 4 have a different amount of elements in their first dimension.  `Dimensions` gives dimensions while the dimension is equal at all levels.  Once it gets to a level with unequal dimensions it stops.

```
array = {{{1}, {2}, {3}}, {{1}, {2}}, {{1}, {2}}};

Dimensions@array
(* {3} *)
```

However, you can `Map` it across the subarrays to get your result.

```
Dimensions /@ array
(* {{3, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 1}} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much